# Strange symbols on page

Tags: css

I get a ">" symbol before some of my text, even though I didn't put it there. The html source code shows it is when the ::before css is called. Have a look at nfsbiathlon.co.za at the bottom as part of the scrolling text and also the sharing icons. I didn't change any css. How do I get rid of it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should ask the author of your theme

Answer (score 1):

That's a font-awesome icon being added with a pseudo-element.

Here's the css that's doing it:

```
#sidebar ul:not(.social-widget) > li:before, article ul > li:before {
    content: "\f0da";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 1px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Using: `article .news-container ul > li:before{display:none}` should get rid of it.